# How can I replace NaN value with mean in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe to fill NaN value as follows:

```
Category           Rating
ART_AND_DESIGN      4.4
AUTO_AND_VEHICLES   4.2
BEAUTY              4.3
BOOKS_AND_REFERENCE 4.3
BUSINESS            4.1
COMICS              4.2
COMMUNICATION       4.2
DATING              4.0
EDUCATION           4.4
```

I intend to replace the following NaN value with the above Rating based on their Categories.

```
App   Category    Rating
 A     DATING      NaN (4.0)
 B     BEAUTY      NaN (4.3)
 C     BUSINESS    NaN (4.1)
```

e.g. Since the dating category has rating 4.0, app A should be filled with 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `df1` after [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html?highlight=s#pandas-dataframe-set-index) to `Category` and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) the `df2['Category']` with `df1['Rating']` as:

```
df1.set_index('Category',inplace=True)
df2['Rating'] = df2['Category'].map(df1['Rating'])
```

Or using [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
df2['Rating'] = df2['Category'].replace(df1['Rating'])

print(df2)
  App  Category  Rating
0   A    DATING     4.0
1   B    BEAUTY     4.3
2   C  BUSINESS     4.1
```

---

Before mapping the dataframes are:

```
print(df1)
                     Rating
Category                   
ART_AND_DESIGN          4.4
AUTO_AND_VEHICLES       4.2
BEAUTY                  4.3
BOOKS_AND_REFERENCE     4.3
BUSINESS                4.1
COMICS                  4.2
COMMUNICATION           4.2
DATING                  4.0
EDUCATION               4.4

print(df2)

  App  Category  Rating
0   A    DATING     NaN
1   B    BEAUTY     NaN
2   C  BUSINESS     NaN
```

Comment: @JoeyLU Check the column names properly using `df.columns` and then use above solution.